# How to make it so a Git repo starts at a certain commit?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I would like to put an old Git Repo I have for a website publicly on GitHub. I cannot do this because the repo contains the original site and its files as well as the current one. The current one is a complete rewrite of the old site and thus, shares no files with it. Sadly, when I was originally creating it, I branched in the repo and did my rewrite there, then merged it back into `master`.

I do not want the old version of the website to be public, but I do want to be able to get to it to check files and content if I need to review something. I'd like to have my repo for the new site start from where I originally branched to now, keeping my recent commit history.

I have some ideas for how this probably could be done, but nothing concrete. Here's what I'm thinking:

1. Rename this repo to `-old` and run some fancy script that takes all commits from a certain starting point and adds then to a new repo.
2. Take the original repo up to the point where it was modified and create a new `-old` version of it. Somehow rewrite Git history in the current repo from a commit to the new one.
3. Create a branch of `master` and somehow rewrite Git history in the current repo from a commit to the new one.
4. **[DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS]** Create a new repo and start over.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716. fell free to vote for tit if you like it.

Comment: I do not see how that solves my issue. It only allows me to go back in time, not remove the past.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `git rebase`, which rewrites history.

Switch to the branch you want to rewrite, run `git rebase --root --interactive`, then rewrite history to your heart's content.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do what I want or do I have to go through hundreds of old commits by hand and tell it to remove them?

Comment: Use your favorite editor to delete all of the commits above the line you want at once.

Comment: I got it working with Sublime Text and found that after I rebased, it only did it on one branch and re-created all commits in a new branch dated today, not the dates the commits happened.